# ¿Se dice "el pareja de baile" para referirse al caballero?

Tags: género

Necesito hablar sobre el baile, y parece que voy a usar la palabra *pareja* mucho: puede significar tanto la dama como el caballero como los dos juntos, si entiendo bien.

Cuando la uso para referirse al caballero, ¿puedo decir "*el* pareja de baile"?  ¿O todavía lleva *la*?

Me parece extraño decir "Miguel es *la* pareja de baile de María", pero español no es mi lengua nativa.

---

I need to speak about dancing, and it looks like I'm going to use the word *pareja* a lot, since it refer to the lady, the gentleman, and the couple, if I am understanding correctly.

When I use *pareja* to refer to the gentleman, can I say "*el* pareja de baile"? Or do I still use *la*?

It seems strange to me to say "Miguel es *la* pareja de baile de María" but I'm not a native Spanish speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Pareja* as a noun is always feminine, regardless whom it refers to, and should use the article *la*.

It is called an *epicene* noun and may refer to anything of either gender despite having a single constant gender. Other epicene nouns include words like *víctima*, *persona*, *bebé* and *miembro*. That said, the DPD recognizes that in Colombia, a masculine form *parejo* has developed, but it will sound very odd to speakers of most dialects.

When used as an adjective, however, it varies in number and gender (*parejo<sub>/a/os/as</sub>*) and means *same/similar* or *flat/straight*.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra **Pareja** es por decirlo de una forma, *"femenina"*, por lo cual siempre va con *la*.

Hay excepciones a la regla, pero no para está palabra justamente.